# What will happen if my Object is bigger than Gen 0 size in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

In an interview, the interviewer asked me the following :

> Lets assume the Gen 0 is of size 5 kb and the object which I am creating is of size 20 kb, what will happen ?

I answered that the CLR will expand the Gen 0 region .

Now I am confused whether it is the right answer or not.

Is it correct?

Comment: What do you think some alternatives might be, and why do you consider them unlikely?

Comment: A Gen 0 *total* size of 5 KB can't happen in practice, making the question a bit more confusing than necessary. The interviewer might have meant the free space available. (We can't just pick "5 KB" as a hypothetical number for the total size, because that would raise the question of how the large object heap is to be used in such a world.)

Comment: I know size of 5 KB cant happen in practice, lets Say  I am making an object 4 times greater than the size of Gen 0, then what will happen.

I have tried answering that CLR will expand the size of GEN 0, but this does not seem convincing and if I would have known the answer then I never have posted it in here.

Comment: Yes, the point is that different answers are possible depending on how we interpret the question in the first place. The threshold for the LOH, the actual size of Gen 0 and the free space available in Gen 0 all matter. A good answer should cover all of this. (I lack the actual insight/time to consult the authoritative sources to write that good answer.) In a *real* .NET runtime, Gen 0 always starts off (much) greater than the LOH threshold, so an object 4 times as large as Gen 0 always goes on the LOH regardless. But that's probably not what the interviewer meant.

Answer (score 1):

The exact specifics depend on the implementation and can vary slightly between framework versions.
Gen0 and Gen1 are not intended to grow, while Gen2 can grow indefinitely. Bursting the limits of Gen0 and 1 will normally trigger a collection.

> Generation 1 and 0 live in something called the ephemeral segment (the first small object segment in each heap) and the size of Gen 1 and Gen 0 can never exceed the size of a segment. If a new segment is created that will become the new ephemeral segment. Gen 2 on the other hand can grow indefinitely (or until you run out of memory) so if you have high memory consumption a large amount of your objects will live in Gen 2.

In my experience with large ETL processes, large data objects tend to get allocated to Gen2 fairly quickly, and Gen2 garbage collection is relatively infrequent so those objects can stick around for some time.

The article [*How does the GC work and what are the sizes of the different generations?*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations/) gives a great overview of this along with some related links.

Comment: So what exactly does happen when asking for 20kb on a 5kb small heap?

Comment: Pretending that the stated sizes are legit and considering size relativity and the basic rules and disregarding specific implementations.... the 20KB object will be promoted to the LOH in Gen 2, possibly after triggering a GC in Gen 0. Of course the only way to tell for sure is to try it.

Comment: No, it will _not_ go to the LOH because it isn't big enough.

Comment: There is no such thing as being "promoted" to the LOH; an object is either allocated in the LOH or it's not. The LOH is only considered part of Gen 2 for administrative purposes. Be careful not to conflate them.

Comment: @Henk, so if being 4x the size of the Gen0 heap isn't big enough to be allocated to the LOH then what is? Remember that the question is hypothetical and we are pretending that the stated sizes are legit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah, semantics - *allocated* is a more appropriate word in this case than *promoted*. In any case it's too late to edit the comment.

Comment: @Henk: agreed, but you've failed to scale that number to fit the hypothetical numbers given.

Comment: It doesn't and shouldn't scale.

Answer (score 1):

You'll end up with Gen 0 of 25K, unless something crazy happens (like another thread allocating a bunch of memory or GC getting trigged because the other generations are too big).

The budget for Gen 0 is generally much bigger than 25k (default is 256K), so allocating that amount won't do anything special. The object itself isn't bigger than 85K, so it won't end up in the Large Object Heap either.

The numbers (5K and 20K) a bit weird, since they aren't anywhere near the thresholds for anything interesting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

LOH is not equals to generation 2

Most object large than 85K will allocate to LOH directly

But generation 2 object can be small, it just survive generation 0 and generation 1, and generation still compact too.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the Generations holds only the object pointer, so no matter how large is the object size the address of that physical space will be small.

Answer (score 0):

GC works in generations Gen0, Gen1 and Gen2. Beside that there is also LOH which is used to store objects bigger than 85kB.

1. Every object must enter the Gen0, this means that Gen0 is bigger
   than 85kB. If object is bigger than 85kB it goes directly to LOH.
2. GC allocate initial memory budget for Gen0, Gen1 and Gen2 which
   depends of the platform, x86 or x64... but these numbers are well
   known
3. Sizes of the Gen0, Gen1 and Gen2 could vary during the runtime as GC
   tries to fine tune the memory consumption and speed up GC

Based on these if new object is created it should enter Gen0 if there is enough budget for that. If there is no enough budget it GC will start collection. Based on the budget of Gen0, Gen1 and Gen2 GC will also decide which generation collection to run. During the collection unreferenced objects will be thrown  away and the referenced objects will be promoted to the next generation. The intention of GC is to keep Gen0 size smallest as possible because Gen0 collection is the most often one but in some cases GC could try to allocate more memory for Gen0.

> Lets assume the Gen 0 is of size 5 kb and the object which I am
>   creating is of size 20 kb, what will happen ?

Let's say if 5kB is free memory of Gen0 GC will start collection and try to free more than 20kB if it is possible. If GC could not reclaim enough memory it will try to grow Gen0 and do a few collections to reclaim enough memory. If even then there is no enough memory `OutOfMemoryException` will be thrown.

Answer (score -2):

Large objects will skip gen 0 and gen 1.

> Small .NET objects are allocated onto the Small Object Heaps (SOH).
>
> ...
>
> Objects larger than 85 KB are allocated onto the Large Object Heap (LOH). They aren't compacted, because of the overhead of copying large chunks of memory. When a full GC takes place, the address ranges of LOH objects not in use are recorded in a free space allocation table instead.

[Source: red-gate article on .NET memory management](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/memory-management-fundamentals)

> Newly allocated objects form a new generation of objects and are implicitly generation 0 collections, **unless they are large objects**, in which case they go on the large object heap in a generation 2 collection.

[Source: MS docs on GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)

Comment: And how does that answer the question?

Comment: @ChrFin . large objects skip gen 0 and 1 and get placed in gen 2 from the start.

Comment: Yes, but 20 KB isn't "large" according to the cited definition. It might be "large" in a hypothetical world where Gen 0 is only 5 KB, but that's not clear from the context.

Comment: No, the LOH is a different heap and the treshold is 85kB. Not relevant here.